# Css Smooth Animaiton

Tags: javascript, html, css

I do wanna make smooth animations. I have a button.
`<button id="scroll">Scroll</button>`

And when i click, it navigates.

`const btn = document.getElementById('scroll') btn.addEventListener('click', () => { window.location.href= '#about' })`

smooth scroll animation

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add *all* the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following CSS to your stylesheet:

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```